# While using script in git extension I'm receiving 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: git, phabricator, git-extensions

I'm using  git extension for managing my repository and phabricator for code review. I have installed git and it works fine in console. To upload on review my changes I'm using script /c start bash.exe --login -i -c "arc diff;read
-p\"Finished! Press Enter\" ". I've created button for executing this script from git extension, however when when I'm pressing it I'm receiving in cmd.exe something like:

Command failed with error #1!
COMMAND
git --version

STDOUT
(empty)

STDERR
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(Run with `--trace` for a full exception trace.)
Finished! Press Enter

It seems to me like git extension opens entity of cmd.exe which doesn't see git. I have configured all path variables. When I'm trying to run this script from cmd.exe it works, but not from git extension. I'm using git extension 2.49

Comment: In which console, git runs fine and in which not . Are you saying that it works fine in git bash ?

Comment: @pravs it works fine both in cmd.exe(I've installed to use cmd as git bash) and git bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that bash from git extension couldn't find git because of broken bash path. I've installed sencha for extJS and it broken my bash path.